# Centering Font-Awesome stackedicons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to center 2 stacked FA icons but text-align doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's the code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
  <h4 class="text-center">Title</h4>
  <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add `.text-center` to the parent `<div>`
- Remove `.text-center` from the `<h4>`
- Add `.text-left` to the `<p>` (unless you want the paragraph text centered also).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p class="text-muted text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

short and simple answer is
add this tag

```
<center>
the text that you wanted to place in center
</center>
```

Comment: No. Just.. no. The `<center>` tag is deprecated and should not be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary">ico#1</i>
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">ico#2</i>
    </span>
    <h4 class="text-center">Title</h4>
    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

.col-md-3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/gzkjp2jk/

Comment: Hard-coding `.col-md-3` to center text is not a good idea. This may adversely affect other elements on the page that use this class.

Comment: @J.Titus reaaaaally bad idea

Comment: @grinmax you should _never_ add new styles to classes you don't own, like `.col-md-3` (bootstrap) or `.fa-stack` (fonts awesome), just add a new class and style it!

Comment: well, this is an example, here is the final decision https://jsfiddle.net/gzkjp2jk/6/